# WPF MVVM DATAGRID select or deselect all rows

Tags: wpf, select, mvvm, datagrid, rows

this is my DataGrid, how do I know if the user has selected or deselected all rows of the DataGrid ?

Thanks

```
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Dati_Viag}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectDat}" Style="{DynamicResource ST_DataGrid}" 
                  CellStyle="{DynamicResource St_DataGridCellStyle}" SelectionMode="Extended" Name="Dg_Dati" >
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="col_A" Binding="{Binding Path=A}" Header="A" Width="250" />
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="col_U" Binding="{Binding Path=B}" Header="B" Width="250" />
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="col_K" Binding="{Binding Path=C}" Header="C"  Width="250" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expose the property `IsSelected` in your viewmodel, and bind it in `DataGrid`:

```
<DataGrid.RowStyle>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsSelected"
                        Value="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush"
                        Value="Blue" />
                <Setter Property="BorderThickness"
                        Value="2" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</DataGrid.RowStyle>
```

Afer this is done, you can use interactive triggers that will call your viewmodels `Command` once an item is selected/deselected:

`<ie:Interaction.Triggers>
      <ie:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
        <ie:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding SelectedItemChangedCommand}"/>
    </ie:EventTrigger>
  </ie:Interaction.Triggers>`

In where you can do simple calculation, such as:

`var allRowsSelected = MyItems.All(x => x.IsSelected)`

Comment: 0

down vote

accept
 

I added your xaml but I get this error message: A 'Binding' cannot be set on the 'Value' property of type 'Trigger'. A 'Binding' can only be set on a DependencyProperty of a DependencyObject

Comment: @Alan392: I changed the binding a little, I forgot `Mode=TwoWay`. It works for me.

Comment: @Erti-ChrisEelmaa but where `IsSelected` is implemented? You ViewModel or in Item? I mean, you have a list of `IsSelected` flags